# Find and replace substrings with mapped values

Tags: c#

Some settings are stored in a string. An example could be

```
string rawWatermarkFormat = "{@Charge}; {Current Date} {Current Time}; Scan Operator: {Scan Operator's User ID}; Page: x/y";
```

Each substring wrapped by **{...}** represents a key for a dictionary. This dictionary contains the value that needs to replace the key. The final string would be

```
string parsedWatermarkFormat = "phosphoric acid; 24.04.2019 14:20; Scan Operator: 123; Page: x/y";
```

(yes, current date and current time are stored in that collection too)

I want to extract these keys, get the correct value from the collection and replace the key with the value. I started with this

```
    public Parse()
    {
        string watermarkFormat = "{@Charge}; {Current Date} {Current Time}; Scan Operator: {Scan Operator's User ID}; Page: x/y"; // batch.get_CustomStorageString(Resources.WATERMARK_FORMAT_KEY);

        int currentFieldStart = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < watermarkFormat.Length; i++)
        {
            char currentCharacter = watermarkFormat[i];

            if (currentCharacter == '{')
            {
                currentFieldStart = i;
            }
            else if (currentCharacter == '}')
            {
                int length = i - currentFieldStart;
                string currentField = watermarkFormat.Substring(currentFieldStart + 1, length - 1);

                string fieldValue = "---"; // access the collection for the correct field value

                watermarkFormat = watermarkFormat
                    .Remove(currentFieldStart, length)
                    .Insert(currentFieldStart, fieldValue);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that if I would replace the substring by using the ranges the string would break. If the key has a length of x and the value has a length of y the replace method would not work for the next fields.

So this `watermarkFormat` example string would result into

`---} {Current Time}; Scan Operator: ---}; Page: x/y`

How can I replace the fields properly?

---

**Edit:** The `rawWatermarkFormat` is just an example string! I don't know it's length, the tokens, etc. So the string could be also this

```
string rawWatermarkFormat = "{Current Date} {Current Date} {Current Date} {Current Date} {Current Date}"
```

or this

```
string rawWatermarkFormat = "{blue car}"
```

I have to extract these strings and get the correct value from the dictionary. I don't know these tokens by myself.

Comment: .net strings are immutable.

Comment: a regular expression might help.

Comment: why a loop and everything? Why cant you use string replace or string format or string interpolation ?

Comment: I think you might be looking for string tokenization to solve your underlying business problem. https://github.com/flipbit/tokenizer

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: Use `Regex.Replace` with the delegate overload, inside the delegate check which keyword you're replacing and look up and return its value. Something like `Regex.Replace(rawWatermarkFormat, @"{(?<keyword>[^}]+)}", me =>
    {
        switch (me.Groups["keyword"].Value.Dump())
        {
            case "@Charge": return "some charge";
            default: return me.Value;
        }
    })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expression as an alternative.

```
string pattern = @"\{[a-zA-Z\-\s\@\']+\}";
string input = "{@Charge}; {Current Date} {Current Time}; Scan Operator: {Scan Operator's User ID}; Page: x/y";
var matches = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
foreach (var match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match);
    // TODO replace
    // var key = match.ToString();
    // input = input.Replace(key, someMethodToGetValue(key.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "")));
}
```

Console output:

```
{@Charge}
{Current Date}
{Current Time}
{Scan Operator's User ID}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be quite easily solved with `Regex.Replace`, using the `MatchEvaluator` delegate overload.

Here's a [LINQPad](https://linqpad.com) example:

```
void Main()
{
    string rawWatermarkFormat = "{@Charge}; {Current Date} {Current Time}; Scan Operator: {Scan Operator's User ID}; Page: x/y";
    Dictionary<string, string> keywordValues = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["@Charge"] = "phosphoric acid",
        ["Current Date"] = "24.04.2019",
        ["Current Time"] = "14:20",
        ["Scan Operator's User ID"] = "123",
    };

    Regex.Replace(rawWatermarkFormat, @"{(?<keyword>[^}]+)}", me =>
    {
        if (keywordValues.TryGetValue(me.Groups["keyword"].Value, out string value))
            return value;
        return me.Value;
    }).Dump();
}
```

This outputs:

```
phosphoric acid; 24.04.2019 14:20; Scan Operator: 123; Page: x/y
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know the tokens during runtime so I can't set them up

Comment: But you do have access to them at runtime? In other words, if you find that one of the keywords are `@Charge`, how would you go about finding the value to replace it with?

Comment: My point was not to say that you can do this using a dictionary, that was just my example, inside the delegate you can write whatever code you want to obtain and return the value for each keyword.

Comment: the collection (dictionary) holds this value and the keyword is just the key for this dictionary

Comment: So what you're saying is that my code would work then?

Answer (score 0):

This can work:

```
 var Charge = "phosphoric acid";
 var CurrentDate = "24.04.2019";
 var CurrentTime = "14:20";
 var ScanOperatorUserID = "123";
 var interpolated = $"{Charge}; {CurrentDate} {CurrentTime}; Scan Operator: {ScanOperatorUserID}; Page: x/y";
 string parsedWatermarkFormat = "phosphoric acid; 24.04.2019 14:20; Scan Operator: 123; Page: x/y";
 Console.WriteLine(interpolated);
 Console.WriteLine(parsedWatermarkFormat);
 Console.ReadKey();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I do it the other way round. Get the dictionary and replace any mention of a key.

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string,string> variable in variableDictionary )
                {
                    fileContent = fileContent.Replace("$(" + variable.Key + ")", variable.Value);
                }
```